# Why a Map is by default immutable in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-2.12

With scala (2.12.2), when creating a new Map in a class

```
private var myMap = Map.empty[String, ActorRef]
```

by default I get a immutable class

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,akka.actor.ActorRef]
```

I was expecting to be mutable because I define it as 'var'

Comment: Scala is functional leaning; you should expect that by default you'll get immutable structures. And as the answer points out, `var` says nothing about the mutability of the object it holds, only the mutability of the reference itself.

Comment: _everything_ is immutable by default in scala. It is generally a good idea to pretend that the `var` keyword, and mutable collections do not exist at all, until you get enough experience with the language to be able to tell the 0.1% of situations when they are actually needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's mutable here is the *reference* held by `myMap`, you can re-assign the variable if you want to. Mutability or immutability of the value pointed to be that reference is a different matter. If you create a mutable map, you can assign it to a variable declared via `val` and can modify the map, but not the variable.